# Apple Magic Mouse quickly loses its charge

Tags: macos, charging, magic-mouse

three days ago I bought an iMac 21.5
The keyboard has 100% charge, but the mouse has already 87%
This is not good. I feel it...

What to do in this situation. Anyone has the same problems ?

Comment: this seems like a community wiki?

Answer (score 2):

It's a known problem: [Battery Life in Magic Mouse Pulls a Disappearing Act](http://macs.about.com/b/2009/11/27/battery-life-in-magic-mouse-pulls-a-disappearing-act.htm)

Here are two tips from the link above.

> The Magic Mouse is supposed to go into
>   hibernation when it detects a lack of
>   use, which should help extend battery
>   life. Turning the Magic Mouse off
>   manually when you're done using it,
>   with the switch on the mouse's belly,
>   should help push battery life a little
>   further.
>
> Another option to get the most life
>   out of the Magic Mouse's batteries is
>   to replace them with either
>   Lithium-Ion AA or rechargeable NiMH
>   (Nickel Metal Hydride) batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Buy [rechargeable batteries](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_6?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=rechargeable+batteries&x=0&y=0&sprefix=rechar) My mouse died after a month.  Co-workers are having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I bought my mouse several months ago and I haven't had any charge issues.  I do manually turn the switch off when I'm done with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd because my Magic Mouse has not died and we've had it for about two months.